# Which Fréchet spaces have a dual that is a Fréchet space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I've read the claim that Fréchet spaces that are not Banach spaces never have a dual that is a Fréchet space, but have not been able to find a proof of this statement. Is it trivial or does someone have a reference?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> For any locally convex and metrizable space $E$, its strong dual is metrizable if and only if $E$ is normable.

This and related properties of (F)-spaces are discussed in detail in *Topological Vector Spaces I* by Köthe (see §29.1, pp. 393-394 in the English edition).

Comment: Thanks, so one has to combine §21.5 (3): "For a Fréchet space, the original topology is equal to the strong topology", with §29.1 (7), which is what you quoted. 

Comment: SO what does this mean for the question, for someone who doesn't have instant recall about the lattice of properties of topological vector spaces?

Comment: @David Roberts: This implies that the claim stated by the OP holds true. The observation is probably due to Grothendieck. 

Comment: A nice way to think of this is as the observation that a LCTVS cannot be a (non-trivial) _projective_ limit and an _inductive_ limit of countably infinite families of Banach spaces at the same time.  Either one family has to be uncountable, or both have to be finite.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: That's really nice and intuitively appealing. 

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Where can one find a proof and detailed discussion of your statement? Thanks!