# Metrizable dual space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

I've got the following questions concerning the theory of locally convex spaces :

Let $X$ be a locally convex metrizable space, what is the necessary and sufficient condition to have its dual $X^*$ metrizable?

Is it possible that $X^*$ is the F-space when $X$ is a locally convex non-complete metrizable space which is not a normed space?

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63383/which-frechet-spaces-have-a-dual-that-is-a-frechet-space/63385#63385

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Fr%C3%A9chet+space#properties_5) cites a theorem that the dual of a Fréchet space $X$ is Fréchet if and only if $X$ is a Banach space. (Reference: paragraph 29.1 (7) in Gottfried Koethe, *Topological Vector Spaces I*.) Even if $X$ is non-complete, the dual of $X$ is isomorphic to the dual of its completion, so $X^\ast$ cannot be Fréchet if $X$ is a non-normable locally convex metrizable TVS.